# IndexedDB testing with Jest & enzyme - ReferenceError: indexedDB is not defined

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme, indexeddb

I'm looking for help with unit tests for my app, where I'm using indexedDB. Before I implemented indexedDB functionality, tests were correct. But now, for all of them I see one error:

```
ReferenceError: indexedDB is not defined
```

Can someone give me an advice how to get rid of that error? I was searching information, and trying different ways to mock `window`, or `indexedDB`, but with no result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This issue is due to Dexie expecting `window.indexedDB` to be defined, this is not the case when running in a headless mode (using Jest) that does not have a true DOM or `window` scope.

Found a solution deep in the Dexie git issues which suggests:

```
const Dexie = require('dexie')

Dexie.dependencies.indexedDB = require('fake-indexeddb')
Dexie.dependencies.IDBKeyRange = require('fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange')
```

We have also had success with:

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';
import indexedDB from 'fake-indexeddb';

Dexie.dependencies.indexedDB = indexedDB;
```

Link to the original issue:
https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/495

Or according to the documentation, you can provide the indexedDB option like:

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';
import indexedDB from 'fake-indexeddb';

var db = new Dexie("MyDatabase", { indexedDB: indexedDB });
```

Link to documentation: http://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie

Comment: Does anyone know when one needs the `FDBKeyRange` dependency (versus just the `indexedDB`?

Answer (score 10):

when using jest, according to the [fakeindexeddb docs](https://npm.io/package/fake-indexeddb),
install,

```
npm install --save-dev fake-indexeddb
```

or

```
yarn add --dev fake-indexeddb
```

then add below code to the jestconfig file

```
"jest": {
    ...
    "setupFiles": [
        "fake-indexeddb/auto"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oluwasegun! This was exactly what I was looking for. Best solution in the thread (for me)!

Comment: Thanks! it was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

If You are using jest and enzyme for testing indexdb or you are using dexie which is a indexDB wrapper which is also used for implementing indexDB api you have to just add these three lines in you global-test.js file .

```js
const Dexie = require('dexie');
Dexie.dependencies.indexedDB = require('fake-indexeddb');
Dexie.dependencies.IDBKeyRange = require('fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange');
```

Now you have to provide this file to jest, show that it can use fake-indexddb instead of original indexDB.

```js
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/test/globals-test.ts']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Dexie (but instead got here when Firebase was throwing an exception on import), the fix was simply adding `require('fake-indexeddb/auto')` into `setupTests.ts` for Jest to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 7.3+  with jest add this to your global-test.ts file:

```
const Dexie = require('dexie');
Dexie.dependencies.indexedDB = require('fake-indexeddb');
Dexie.dependencies.IDBKeyRange = require('fake-indexeddb/lib/FDBKeyRange');
```

then load the file in jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules'],
    setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/image.js',
        '@lib/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/lib/$1'
    },
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsConfigFile: 'src/tsconfig.spec.json'
        },
        __TRANSFORM_HTML__: true
    },
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/test/globals-test.ts']
};
```